Is this second proof of Lagrange Polynomial known or published before?
This proof came to my mind and I think it out by myself, so I'm not certain if this proof is published by other sources before. The Lagrange Polynomial used for interpolation can be proved by uniqueness theorem, here I have another more direct way to derive it.
The original problem is equivalent to finding the $n$th order polynomial passing $n+1$ sampling points, with the polynomial the desired interpolating point can be evaluated.
Let $(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1),... (x_n, y_n)$ be the $n+1$ points passing through the polynomial, this is equivalent to the matrix equation
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & x_n^3 & \cdots& x_n^n \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
\vdots \\
a_{n} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y_0 \\
y_1 \\
\vdots \\
y_{n} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The matrix on the left hand side is a Vandermonde matrix, and can be denoted by $V$, the $a_0, a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ are coefficients of the desired polynomial. The above equation may be written as
$$
V\alpha=\gamma
$$
for succinct. Let $(x, y)$ be the interpolating point waiting to be evaluated, with the coefficients of polynomial at hand, the $y$ point can be quickly evaluated. Let $\mathbf{x}=(1, x, x^2,...,x^n)^T$. We have
$$
y = \mathbf{x}^T\alpha = \mathbf{x}^T V^{-1}\gamma,
$$
i.e.,
$$
y = \begin{pmatrix}1, x, x^2, ..., x^n\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
\vdots \\
a_{n} \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}1, x, x^2, ..., x^n\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & x_n^3 & \cdots& x_n^n \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_0 \\
y_1 \\
\vdots \\
y_{n} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
One can see core of the problem is the invertiblity of the Vandermonde matrix $V$, and the solvability of the polynimial coefficients. Here we do not seek to invert the matrix $V$, but focus on the linear euqation to solve $a_i$.
To solve $V\alpha = \gamma$, by cramer's rule,
$$
a_i = \frac{\det(V_i)}{\det(V)} = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \cdots & y_0 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & \cdots & y_1 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \cdots & y_n & \cdots& x_n^n \\
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & x_n^3 & \cdots& x_n^n \\
\end{vmatrix}}
$$
Then the result $y$ is obtained with the coefficients of the polynomial.
$$
y = \sum_{i=0}^n x^i\frac{\det(V_i)}{\det(V)} = \frac{\det(V_0)}{\det(V)} + x \frac{\det(V_1)}{\det(V)} + x^2\frac{\det(V_2)}{\det(V)} + \cdots + x^n\frac{\det(V_n)}{\det(V)} 
$$
Using this expansion, we will obtain the forumula of Lagrange Polynomial avoiding the inversion of Vandermonde matrix. We will expand the expression in two folds, i.e., the $\det(V_i)$ will also be expanded by the $n$th column, those columns occupied by $y_i$. For $\det(V_i)$ we have
$$
\det(V_i) = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \cdots & y_0 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & \cdots & y_1 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & \cdots & y_n & \cdots& x_n^n \\
\end{vmatrix} = \sum_{j=0}^n
(-1)^{i+j}y_j\det(V_{ij})
$$
Here $\det(V_{ij})$ is the determinant of the matrix, by deleting the $i$th column and $j$th row of $V$. Substituting back, we have
$$
y = \sum_{i=0}^n x^i\frac{\det(V_i)}{\det(V)} = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n x^i\frac{(-1)^{i+j}y_j\det(V_{ij})}{\det(V)}
$$
Change the order of operator, the original formula becomes
$$
\frac{1}{\det(V)}\sum_{j=0}^n y_j\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i+j}x^i\det(V_{ij})
$$
Coincidentally, the term inside the second summation equals another expansion of Vandermonde determinant, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i+j}x^i\det(V_{ij}) = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & \cdots & x^n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & x_n^3 & \cdots& x_n^n \\
\end{vmatrix} = \det(V_j^*)
$$
Going back, we have an expression involving both Vandermonde determinant,
$$
y = \sum_{j=0}^n y_j\frac{\det(V_j^*)}{\det(V)}
$$
For a Vandermonde matrix, its determinant is
$$
\det(V) = \prod_{0 \leq i < j \leq n} (x_j - x_i),
$$
eliminating same terms we get the expression of Lagrange Polynomial.
$$
y = \sum_{j=0}^n y_jl_j(x) \\ l_j(x) = \prod_{0 \leq m \leq n, m\neq j}\frac{x - x_m}{x_j - x_m} = \frac{(x - x_0)}{(x_j - x_0)} \cdots \frac{(x - x_{j-1})}{(x_j - x_{j-1})}\frac{(x - x_{j+1})}{(x_j - x_{j+1})} \cdots \frac{(x - x_n)}{(x_j - x_n)}
$$
It is interesting that the $l_j$ terms equals to the fraction of two Vandermonde determinants. To elaborate this, we can switch the the $j$th row and the last row of both the nominator and denominator, i.e.,
$$
\frac{\det(V_j^*)}{\det(V)} = \frac{ \begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & \cdots & x^n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & x_n^3 & \cdots& x_n^n \\
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_j & x_j^2 & x_j^3 & \cdots & x_j^n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & x_n^3 & \cdots& x_n^n \\
\end{vmatrix}} = \frac{ \begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & x_n^3 & \cdots& x_n^n \\
1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & \cdots & x^n \\
\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & x_0^3 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1^3 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & x_n^3 & \cdots& x_n^n \\
1 & x_j & x_j^2 & x_j^3 & \cdots & x_j^n\\
\end{vmatrix}}
$$
Only the last row, at the same time the first few terms, of the expansion of the Vandermonde determinant is different, and the rest are the same.

Seems good and interesting.

It is known, and heavy for what it is.

Do you know where?
